# How can I properly save a FullCalendar event to a database?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I'm having some struggle with FullCalendar as I'm not good at JavaScript.
I'm using a Drag-n-Drop Event calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging) and I'm having some problem to save an event when I drag it to the calendar.

The code I use to save it is the following:

```js
             eventReceive: function (event) {
                  console.log(event.start);
                  console.log(event.title);
                  console.log(event.allDay);
                  console.log(event.eventID);
                  var data = {
                      Id: event.eventID,
                      Titulo: event.title,
                      Inicio: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'),
                      Fim: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') : null,
                      DiaInteiro: event.allDay,
                      Cor: event.eventColor
                  };
                  SaveEvent(data);
               },
            });

            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Escala/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            calendar.render();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
```

But as you can see, when I drag an event into the calendar, I have these problems:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2gyV.png)

I have an Event class with these attributes

```
public class Evento
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Inicio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Termino { get; set; }
    public bool DiaInteiro { get; set; }
    public string Cor { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have any ideia how can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar are you using? Because if it's version 4, I suggest you study the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive a little more carefully, because if you do, you'll see that the parameter passed into eventReceive is not just an event but a more complex object, of which the event data is just one part. In that case, `eventReceive: function (info) { console.log(info.event.start);` ...etc would be the correct approach.

Comment: Either that, or the data you've defined in the draggable element is incorrect (and thus nothing is present in the object received by the calendar). You didn't show us that code, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: It worked for me using `info.event.title`, `moment(info.event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')` etc instead, that was the problem. Thanks, buddy! :)